# How to tackle Not Null constraints in OLE DB Destination in SSIS Package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, data-migration

I'm new to SSIS Package. I want to transfer data from source to destination database which has different table structures. My Data Flow is from **OLE DB Source** to **OLE DB Destination** [image]

I have named **OLE DB Source** as **Patient Source** and in OLE DB Source Editor, the connection is made with Source Database and in **Data Access Mode** I have selected **SQL command** and SQL command text as follows

`select ppFName, ppLName, ppPersonalNbr, ppEmailOne from pat_Patients` and as well as I have previewed  the data, it shows **75 rows**.

I want to transfer these four fields from this database to my source database table named **Person** and its table structure as above.
[image]

The connection is made in OLE DB Destination Editor,

[image] and the mappings as follows,

[image]

When I run the project, my data flow is as follows,

[image] 
and I got three errors, in which first error states

`[OLE DB Destination [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TenantId', table 'test_9.dbo.Person'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.".`

I know that TenantId and PersonId are both not null and 'foreign key' & 'primary key identity' respectively.

But I want to enter **TenantId** as '**1**' and **PersonId** as Identity i.e., auto-increment for all **75 rows** from **Patient Source**. As well as I want to enter **AddedBy** as '**1**' and **AddedDateTime** to system current datetime.

I don't know how to achieve the above requirements, please anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `derived transformation` to assign 1 when the `TenantId` is null

```
ISNULL([TenantId]) ? 1 : [TenantId]
```

Similary for `AddedBy` column add an expression as `1` and for `AddedDateTime` column as `GETDATE()`

Comment: Will u please tell where I have to use **derived transformation** or **Derived Column** because I'm new SSIS?

Comment: Just after `Source`  add `Derived Transformation`. Inside the editor for the `Derived column tab` Select `replace AddedBy` and in the expression write as `1`. Similarly do it for other 2 columns

Comment: I have added *Derived Column* after *Patient Source* in dataflow. In derived editor, it shows only the source columns with *replace* word in *Derived Column tab*. I didn't found destination columns such as *Replace 'TenantId'* or *Replace 'AddedBy'* in that tab.

Comment: I thought `TenantID, AddedBy and AddedDatetime` columns are coming from source. That's the reason i told u to use `replace by` in the editor.  Select `Add as a new column` in editor and in the derived column name specify it as `AddedBy`

Comment: If I add *TenantId* & *AddedBy* as new columns in Derived Column tab, then what will happen to the existing *TenantId* & *AddedBy* in Destination, whether it will replace or add new columns with already existing columns in Destination Database Table?

Comment: Currently as per the diagram you have attached in the question `TenenatID AddedBy` are not mapped in the destination. There are represented as `Ignore` in the editor. So you have to map the newly created columns in the `Derived Transformation` to the columns in the destination

Comment: thanks a lot praveen. I got the output. I do have some more queries, first I'll try. If I didn't get what I need, then I'll get back to you.