# How to select a table from one machine to another using sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have explained the scenario below:

I am having two servers:

1. server 1
2. server 2

In **both the servers** I have **Sql Server 2008 r2**.

In **server 1**, I have a database named "**DB_Server1**" and in **server 2**, a database named "**DB_Server2**".

In **DB_server1** database, I have a table named "**TB_Server1**" and in **DB_Server2**, a table named "**TB_Server2**".

My requirement is, in DB_Server1, I'm going to write a stored procedure which selects the table "TB_Server2" from DB_Server2 which is located in the server 2.

How can I achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Take a look on this [Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987481/query-to-copy-rows-from-sql-server-to-another-sql-server/22032197#22032197

This may help you

Answer (score 2):

you can use **linkserver**

at first select Server1

step 1: exec sp_addlinkedserver 'Server2'

step 2: select * from [Server2].[DB_Server2].TB_Server2

Answer (score 0):

Use **Linked Server**:

Allows you to query databases and tables on remote servers as though they are part of the local database. Very easy to setup (just call exec sp_addlinkedserver) and once defined uses nothing but plain old SQL.

[Here](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) is a simple tutorial about how to create a linked server. After creating linked server, we can query it as follows:

```
select * from LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
```

[Click here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suthish_nair/linked-servers-in-sql-server-2008/) for another tutorial.
Read more about Linked Servers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx).

Comment: I have already saw that link. After right clicking the "Linked servers" in "Server Objects", I clicked "New Linked Server" and I don't know what be done further.

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial in the answer?

Comment: After selecting `New Linked Server`, type your LinkedServer Name and select server type and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can create linked server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff772782.aspx)