# Copy a table with data to another db in SQL server 2005 express

Tags: copy, sql-server-2005-express

I have a database with a table. I want copy it along with the data to another database.

How can I do this in SQL server 2005 express?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://aspalliance.com/888

Comment: Similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server

Comment: > Similar post: stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/… 
Note that the accepted answer will only copy the data; look at the answer further down which also advises how to script the table creation as well.