# SQL Cross-Database Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy tables from one database to another in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server)

I am trying to copy the data of one table into another table and both are of different Database say DB1 and DB2.Tables to create are TB1,TB2.but I am facing problem in doing so.The approach is
`SELECT * 
INTO temp2.dbo.B
FROM temp.dbo.A`
and the error coming is

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ".." LINE 2: INTO ui..golden_records_data ^
```

*** Error ***

ERROR: syntax error at or near ".." SQL state: 42601 Character: 19

Comment: [Already asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server) You can visit this link.It is same as you what you want.This question already asked.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
insert into database1.table1(fields) select fields from database2.table1;
```