# Transfer data from one database to another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to fetch the data from one database and insert in to another database table? I can't to do this. Please help me in transferring data from one to another.

Comment: Many ways to do this. What are your requirements? "I can't do this." What have you tried? What error do you see?

Comment: The structure of the question leaves somewhat clear the author is completely lost. You can of course judge him by beginning his journey over here. I would just write an answer.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, below are two options:

Option 1
- Right click on the database you want to copy

- Choose 'Tasks' > 'Generate scripts'
- 'Select specific database objects'
- Check 'Tables'
- Mark 'Save to new query window'
- Click 'Advanced'
- Set 'Types of data to script' to 'Schema and data'
- Next, Next

You can now run the generated query on the new database.

Option 2

- Right click on the database you want to copy
- 'Tasks' > 'Export Data'
- Next, Next
- Choose the database to copy the tables to
- Mark 'Copy data from one or more tables or views'
- Choose the tables you want to copy
- Finish

Comment: in sql server 2008 to copy all data of each table you should enable Script Data in 'Tasks' > 'Generate scripts'==>Script Wizard==> choose Script Option part

Comment: Option 1 I get an error on `preparing data` on the end step. Option 2 I get an error before `Choose the database to copy the tables to`

Comment: i have data in both the databases .. will your solution help in this situation?

Comment: In SSMS 2019 scripting data is no longer supported.  You must use export.

Comment: Facing same issues as mentioned by @Emaborsa

Comment: What about the constraints that are there in the destination server?

Answer (score 19):

Example for insert into values in One database table into another database table running on the same SQL Server

```
insert into dbo.onedatabase.FolderStatus
(
  [FolderStatusId],
  [code],
  [title],
  [last_modified]
)

select [FolderStatusId], [code], [title], [last_modified]
from dbo.Twodatabase.f_file_stat
```

Comment: this worked for me, however, in SqlExpress 2014 I had to use the .. notation found in other answers i.e. 

INSERT INTO [db1]..table1( ID, MetaTitle )
SELECT ID, MetaTitle FROM [db2]..table1

Comment: The order should be `onedatabase.dbo.FolderStatus` and `Twodatabase.dbo.f_file_stat`. Or you use the `..` notation as @AdamHey pointed out.

Answer (score 12):

For those on Azure, follow these modified instructions from Virus:

1. Open SSMS.
2. Right-click the Database you wish to **copy data from**.
3. Select **Generate Scripts** >> **Select Specific Database Objects** >> Choose the tables/object you wish to transfer.
   **strong text**
4. In the "Save to file" pane, click **Advanced**
5. Set "Types of data to script" to **Schema and data**
6. Set "Script DROP and CREATE" to **Script DROP and CREATE**
7. Under "Table/View Options" set relevant items to TRUE. Though I recommend setting all to TRUE just in case. You can always modify the script after it generates.
8. Set filepath >> Next >> Next
9. Open newly created SQL file. Remove "Use" from top of file.
10. Open new query window on destination database, paste script contents (without using) and execute.

Comment: Can't believe this is still the best solution out there 7 years later, but this was about the only thing that worked for me. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 9):

if both databases are on same server and you want to transfer entire table (make copy of it) then use simple select into statement ...

```
select * into anotherDatabase..copyOfTable from oneDatabase..tableName
```

You can then write cursor top of sysobjects and copy entire set of tables that way.

If you want more complex data extraction & transformation, then use SSIS and build appropriate ETL in it.

Comment: If you use the select * into syntax the keys and constraints will not be copied

Answer (score 5):

You can use visual studio 2015. Go to **Tools** => **SQL server** => **New Data comparison**

Select **source** and **target** Database.

Comment: it's a great tool. although the comparison is slowly :)

Answer (score 3):

1. You can backup and restore the database using Management Studio.
2. Again from Management Studio you can use "copy database".
3. you can even do it manually if there is a reason to do so. I mean manually create the target db and manually copying data by sql statements...

can you clarify why you ask this? Is it that you dont have expierience in doing it or something else?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple options and depend on your needs.
See the following links:

1. [Copying Data Between Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190923%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
2. [Copy tables from one database to another in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 2):

These solutions are working in case when target database is blank.
In case when both databases already have some data you need something more complicated http://byalexblog.net/merge-sql-databases

Comment: That's all well and good, except that guy drops FKs and PKs and doesn't seem to put them back... Also aren't answers supposed to be more than effectively just a link to someone else's stuff?

Comment: @Jon Why do you want to restore PK and FK in Source database? It is better to copy it an throw into trash after export.

Comment: Because what I'm trying to do is sync up two environments (i.e. bring QA down to Develop so that we don't have to duplicate all of their data entry).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by a T-SQL statement, if you are aware that `FROM` clause can specify database for table name.

```
insert into database1..MyTable
select from database2..MyTable
```

Here is how Microsoft explains the syntax: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> If the table or view exists in another database on the same instance of SQL Server, use a fully qualified name in the form `database.schema.object_name`.

`schema_name` can be omitted, like above, which means the default schema of the current user. By default, it's `dbo`.

Add any filtering to columns/rows if you want to. Be sure to create any new table before moving data.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this programmatically between two different databases could involve a scheduled job using a linked server. But linked servers require DBA-level knowledge to set up. If you can't use a linked server, just write a program that 1. Reads a row from the source table and 2. Inserts it into the target table. The programmer just needs to use a connection string that has INSERT privileges into the target database table. I have solved this problems using both approaches.