# Migrate data to an existing OracleDB

Tags: mysql, oracle, data-migration

I have a MySql Database for the previous version of my application, now The application is rebuilt with a somewhat different data model and using Oracle DB.

I want to migrate data and pictures from the old database to new Database, When I search for this topic Oracle recommends using Sql Developer and has some tutorials about it but I am not sure that's what I really need. I think these tools and procedures are for "creating" a new database model when you give your existing model. But I already have a second database with different mappings and data model etc. How can I migrate data in this case, is this all need to be done manually by sql scripts?

Actually I need an action plan to start, at the moment I'm stuck with no clue

I have the dump of previous database

Comment: go through this link..it may help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028805/transfer-data-from-one-database-to-another-database

Comment: @Revanayya Hiremath tnx but that link assumes you have the same data model in your bot DB's

Comment: @Spring.... or use Converters..have a look  http://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a new data model you will encounter many data transformations in your scenario. So it will be a tedious task if you choose to do the migration using SQL Developer or  pure PL/SQL scripts. So I recommend you to use an ETL tool like Talend Open Studio, Oracle Data Integator, etc.