# How can I programmatically export and import java db with its data?

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, javadb

I have lots of data to be exported from one machine and imported into another. Therefore I need to write a Java application to export the entire database along with its data and then run another java code to import it into another machine. I saw ddlutils but it doesn't seem to have an official release yet. Also examples in there are not explanatory enough for a beginner. Is there a way to do this? Any code samples would be much appreciated.

Comment: instead of re-inventing the wheel .... try using any existing ETL tool ... for example Talend

Comment: Is it just "take all the data of A and copy them to B" or is merging with already existing data (at B) required?

Comment: I don't see any benefits doing it in java instead of on the db side itself with a bkp or something. Unless you want to edit a bunch of the data in the proccess.

Comment: @Fildor If there are data already available, then I should merge it. Else I need to insert them fresh

Comment: @mayooran I still think it is simply easier (and way faster since you don't need to read every data in Java) to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028805/transfer-data-from-one-database-to-another-database)

Comment: If you only want an exact copy of the whole database, you simply can copy the database folder.