# how can I transmit data from DB1 into DB2?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to transmit information from DB1 (external reachable) to DB2 (only internal reachable). This should be done every morning if there are new data which arent transmitted to DB2 already.

Any Ideas? I want to use PHP.

Comment: What kind of databases are being used?

Comment: @Max MySQL DB with PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer data from one database to another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028805/transfer-data-from-one-database-to-another-database)