# Move data from one db to another

Tags: mysql, sql

My task is move the particular set of data from db to another db both are mysql but ran in different instances, in that old db i used mappings(one-to-one and one-to-many). If it is possible to move the data like in this scenario?

how i move the particular set of data from one db to another in mysql

Comment: Hello. What have you tried, show us. What failed ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028805/transfer-data-from-one-database-to-another-database

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting the data from the old database and import to the new one? As a visual tool, you can use MySQL Workbench for export/import.
[image]