# copy tables with data to another database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to copy the **tables with data from one database to another** using **Query**. I know how to copy tables with data within a database. But I was not sure about how to do the same for copying between two databases.

I have to copy huge number of tables, so I need any fast method using query...

Anybody please help out...Thanks in advance...

Comment: i think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the same way to copy the tables within one database, the [**`SELECT INTO`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) but use a fully qualified tables names `database.schema.object_name` instead like so:

```
USE TheOtherDB;

SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM TheFirstDB.Schemaname.OldTable
```

This will create a new table `Newtable` in the database `TheOtherDB` from the table `OldTable` whih belongs to the database`TheFirstDB`

Answer (score 12):

1. Right click on the database, select tasks and click on Generate Scripts.
2. In the resultant pop-up, choose options as required (click advanced), to drop and create table, drop if exists, etc.
3. Scroll down and choose "Schema and Data" or "Data Only"  or "Types of data to script (2008 R2)"as required.
4. Save to file and execute on the destination DB.

Advantages -

- Can be executed against the destination DB, even if it is on another server / instance
- Quickly script multiple tables, with data as needed

Warning - Might take quite a while to script, if the tables contain a large amount of data.

Rajan

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.MyOtherTable (Col0, Col1)
SELECT Col0, Col1 FROM DB1.dbo.MyTable
```

Both table column's must have same data types..

Answer (score 1):

Below SQL Query will copy SQL Server table schema & data from one database to another database. You can always table name (SampleTable) in your destination database.

```
SELECT * INTO DestinationDB.dbo.SampleTable FROM SourceDB.dbo.SampleTable
```