# mvc ef6 migration history deleted, want to restore but keep data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

I am working on a ef6 mvc projeect and i deleted all migration records. I want to continue on the project with the current dj. I have a lot of data in there. 
I added an initial migration but I can't add migration after adding a model. As the tables that are in the initial migration already exist in the db.

Can someone help me how I can keep my zn, and get migrations going again?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try:

1. Backup the DB as it is FIRST.
2. You can try and restore the DB with migration history to a DIFFERENT database.
3. Then copy the __MigrationHistory over.

eg copying table. (SQL server example) You may be using another DB... sorry
[Copy tables from one database to another in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server)

Then test if you that has resolved issue.