# SQL Server 2012 - remove table data and copy table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two databases in SQL Server 2012 with the same tables. So I have databases `A` and `B` with tables `a, b, c, d` in both.

I would like to delete all the data from `B.a` and copy the data from `A.a` into `B.a`. I would like to do this with all the tables, clear them out in B but keep the tables then refill them with the table data from A.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Truncate all table in B. Then insert table B using Insert Table Select From syntax.

Comment: Backup DB A and Restore as DB B

Comment: I'd go with T McKeown's response, if that is a viable option.

Comment: Both of the databases have different names. I thought it would not let you restore to a database with a different name.

Comment: I tried to do the backup/restore but it did not work. They are two distinct database's I just want to clear one out and move the data to it.

Comment: Are you able to query across databases? Maybe they are on the same instance or linked servers? Like from DB B can you query DB A?

Comment: Important: Do you have any IDENTITY columns or any Foreign Keys? If not, then its not too hard. If so, then it can be a ton of work, depending on how many...

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server .  You can do the 4 tables individuals w the copy wizard, or the import/export wizard, I forget which one.  Backup restore overrides your target database producing unintended consequences sometimes, so unless your looking to do a restore, stick w the SSMS wizards, or write your own queries, I'd use the wizard.

Comment: Do you want the databases `A` and `B` to be exactly the same after you're done (except for the name)? Then I would suggest the backup and restore strategy. If you only need to copy data for a number of tables then I would look into the Import and Export wizard. It can be configured to delete the data first and then load in the new data.

Comment: FYI, BACKUP/RESTORE does *not* have a problem with differing database names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

1. Back the destination DB. this is as a roll back plan
2. Export all records from the source database "A" using the following steps

   - Right Click on DB
   - Select Tasks
   - Select Generate Scripts, Wizard dialog will popup
   - From the popup select the tables you would like to export
   - In the "Set Scripting Options" -> Click Advanced -> make sure to set "Types of Data to script" to "Data Only"
   - this will generate script with insert statements
3. Open the destination database and do the following steps

   - Truncate the destination tables
   - Run the scripts generated from step 2

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you that worked after a little tinkering, thanks everyone for the help.