# Error when using the instance name in query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases, both on the same server the default is named `XXX` the second is `XXX\MSSQKSERVERVIS7`

I need to copy a table from the second db to the default. When I attempt to use the server name I get an error that the \ is incorrect syntax. The query is quite simple I run the query from the default instance

```
  SELECT * 
  INTO table 
  FROM XXX\MSSQLSERVERVIS7.[db].[dbo].[table]
```

If I put brackets around the server name I get the error that the object doesn't exist.

Comment: This SO answer may provide some additional help for your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

What you have is 2 SQL Server instances, both running on the same physical server.  XXX is the default instance and XXX\MSSQKSERVERVIS7 is a named instance.  From the SQL Server perspective they are 2 separate servers.  You can't directly query between them without a little extra configuration.

You need to [create a linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) from the default instance (XXX) to the named instance (XXX\MSSQLSERVERVIS7).  Then you would use the linked server name in your SELECT.

Comment: The server is linked.  I can transfer the opposite direction without a problem.  I have checked using SELECT * FROM sys.servers.   Both have the other server as a linked server but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It was in the security settings when linking the servers.  One was set correctly and worked. The other wasn't.