# How to copy a table from database A on a linked server to database B?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I need to write a T-SQL query (that I will use as a SQL job) to copy a table (say, `T1`) located in a database (say, `db1`) on a linked Server to another database (say, `db2`).

Table `T1` does not currently exist in database `db2`.

Assuming the table schema of `T1` on the linked server is `[xxx.xx.x.xx].db2.dbo.T1`, how do I write this T-SQL query?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy tables from one database to another in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `OPENDATASOURCE`. In Your destination Server database, Just Run

```
SELECT 
    *
    INTO dbo.DestinationTable
    FROM 
       OPENDATASOURCE
       (
          'SQLOLEDB', 
          'Data Source=SourceServer;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPass'
       ).SourceDatabase.dbo.SourceTable;
```

Comment: If I understand well, the Data Source=SourceServer will be Data Source=[xxx.xx.x.xx] based on my example.

Comment: Yes, Maybe without Square brackets

Comment: It is in the form of an IP Address...so I guess I will need those square brackets.

Comment: In that case Yes I guess. Try with both

Comment: It worked without the square brackets! I do have a small question: If I schedule this query to run as a daily job, will it still work the next day if, after the first run, the table has already been created in the target database?

Comment: It should work unless you made some changes in the Server side like User Credentials update