# SQL Select INTO Query

Tags: sql, select

I am trying to running the following command to copy a table to another database and it is saying incorrect syntax near "tbl_SecurityNamespace". Any ideas? TIA

```
select * into ForMSDB  tbl_SecurityNamespace
from Tfs_configuration  
go
```

Comment: Get rid of 'ForMSDB'??

Comment: Is ForMSDB a linked server?

Comment: what technology is this?   SQL Server?  The ForMSDB looks incorrect unless that is the DB name, then if it is SQL Server it should be ForMSDB.dbo.tbl_SecurityNamespace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy tables from one database to another in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187770/copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as

```
select * into ForMSDB..tbl_SecurityNamespace
from Tfs_configuration;
```

Comment: I'm doubting this since the user specified "another database"... and ForMSDB sounds an awful lot like the name of another database...

Comment: thank you now the error is Invalid object name 'Tfs_configuration'.

Comment: Then you are missing that table or you are not pulling from the correct db - or its in another schema that you need to specify

Answer (score 2):

If it's another database in the same environment:

```
select * into ForMSDB..tbl_SecurityNamespace
from Tfs_configuration
```